# How to exit out of console application with windows form running

Tags: c#, winforms, console, exit

I can't seem to stop my application from running. It opens a console window and runs some commands from a windows form and then i just want it to close down but the console window stays open. This is the code I have so far. I guess I should add it is a console app with a windows from within it which I am using. It is keeping both the windows form and console window open.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //************************Run Windows Form
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new loadPerformanceChart());
        if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.MessageLoop)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Here is the methods I am running in the windows form.

```
public partial class loadPerformanceChart : Form
{
    public loadPerformanceChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;  //Minimises windows form to taskbar
        commitToDataBase();
    }
```

When I use `this.Close()` in the windows form it shuts it down but then I get in error in the main program that says: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in the System.Windows.forms.dll Additional Information: Cannot access a disposed object.

Furthermore, if I used System.Forms.Application.Exit(); in the main program it closes down the windows form but I am left with the console window open. Interestingly, I have tried to use a Console.Writeline() and it is not showing in the console yet the program is doing what it is supposed to be doing

Comment: When you click on close button it doesn't close ?

Comment: When I click on the close button it does close. But if I leave the this.Close() under commitToDataBase(); it throws an excption which I outlined above in the static main program.

Comment: Grant...this is what I did but it didh't work it threw an exception.

Comment: commit to database opens a connection to SQL and then puts data into it via excel worksheets, which it downloads from smartsheets. So one of these processes might not be closing?